# .NET MVC Controller not binding to object type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Very straight forward $.post(url, data)

data is this object

```
                 var model = {
                    applNo: pdAppNo,
                    amount: 999,
                    schldDate: new Date(),
                    userId: "corey",
                    tdcId: "234234234"
                };
```

Calling an MVC controller that is setup like

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostScheduleMakeUpPayment(object model)
    {
        //return _updateTdc.ProcessMakeUpPayment(applNo, amount, schldDate, userId, tdcId);
        return Json("Success:True");
    }
```

Inside the 'model' of the controller its not showing the json data, only '{object}'

So MVC won't allow me to post json to object type?

Comment: Create a new named class for your `object`. Auto binding needs property names.

Answer (score 1):

You need the create named class.

```
public class TestModel
{
public string applNo {get;set;}
public int amount{get;set;}
public DateTime schldDate{get;set;}
public string userId{get;set;}
public string tdcId{get;set;}
}

   [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostScheduleMakeUpPayment(TestModel model)
    {
        //return _updateTdc.ProcessMakeUpPayment(model.applNo, model.amount, model.schldDate, model.userId, model.tdcId);
        return Json("Success:True");
    }
```

Comment: Right I understand that. I guess my question is how do I allow for object types as my controller parameters? I guess I could just make the type of string and inspect the Json to see if it will be deserialized into different types. Basicall i want one method that will control posting scheduled payments in their types might not always be the same.

Comment: If you want to ask another thing , you can ask like that. If you want to return object as Json you can write like that. return new Json({Success:true,Message:"No Error"});   you can handle response from client side.

Comment: I'm not talking about return type. The parameter type only..the request.  Could I make a custom model binder?  I have not found any examples of this I can relate my issue to.

Comment: @chdev77 If you really can't impose some structure to your input, you could pass everything as a string instead of an object then extract `<string, string>` key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

A Json string is a collection of pairs key-value. You can post your object as a json string and use a function to add to a dictionary its values, and then use it in controller function. For example:

```
public static Dictionary<string,object> BinderModel(string model)
{
    Dictionary<string,JToken> result = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(model);
    foreach (JProperty x in (JToken)jObject )
    {
         result.Add(x.Name,x.Value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then your controller function like this

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostScheduleMakeUpPayment(string model)
{
    Dictionary<string,object> values = BinderModel(jsonString);
    //return _updateTdc.ProcessMakeUpPayment(values["applNo"], values["amount"], values["schldDate"], values["userId"], values["tdcId);
    return Json("Success:True");
}
```

The type of model values depends on the types of ProcessMakeUpPayment input parameters. You may need to do some conversion before you call it or in it

Comment: I thought of this too, but your js model must be flattened.

Answer (score 0):

I guess object type parameters on MVC controllers are not supported/bad design.  Along with MVC not supporting generic types on its view/Razor syntax.